# .htaccess does not work for subdomain.domain.com but domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

I'm a beginner with .htaccess files but I could research some rules I needed to f.e. hide php extensions or redirect index to root.

But when I try to reach my domain over a subdomain I get an server error or the message that I am not allowed to access. (I played around removing rules but in the end not a single rule worked for the subdomain).

Is there something additional I need write into the .htaccess file to make them work for both subdomain and my normal domain, like:

www.domain.com (works)

subdomain.domain.com (doesn't work)

I setup the subdomain with parallels confixx which generally points at myserver.com/subfolder.

Here are my used rules:

```
    #redirect 404 to index
    ErrorDocument 404 http://subdomain.domain.com

    #hide .php ending
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

    # gzip compression.
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      # html, xml, css, and js:
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript application/json
      # webfonts and svg:
      <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://subdomain.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: First things first, have you a catch-all DNS entry for `*.domain.com`? try pinging `subdomain.domain.com`.  If it resolves to your hosting server then it's a rule issue.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. I just called my host and they gave me an answer. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a message from my server-support.

If you are using Parallels Confixx to manage your domains mod_rewrite has to be enabled from your host **manually** which is needed for the .htaccess to work on here.